# Django, deploying on Azure (IIS) django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application() could not be imported

Tags: python, django, azure, iis

i'm trying to deploy django on my azure web App and have followed some tutorials regarding this matters.The problem is that i always get "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."  page instead. After checking on kudu and log files here's what i get:

[image: error log]

here is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Python FastCGI"
           path="*"
           verb="*"
           modules="FastCgiModule"
           scriptProcessor="D:\Python27\python.exe|D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py"
           resourceType="Unspecified"
           requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()" />
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot;D:\home\site\wwwroot\testbenda2" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="cpcapung.settings" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

i've checked and make sure that the project runs fine on localhost, it even runs fine on travis, the only problem seems to be when i deploy it to azure with an IIS based sever.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I know this is not an answer, but at this moment you can deploy a Docker containers based on a custom Docker image to [Azure App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-using-custom-docker-image).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i'm trying to setup CD using travis for this project so i'm afraid it's not possible for me to use docker inside azure app service and having it also continuously deployed using travis.

Comment: actually, have looked it up and it's possible to do so.. although it will require much efforts.. and would still prefer to get the current problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Just according to your `web.config` file, there are some configuration which be missing & incorrect.

As reference, there is a [Django sample app project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-python-get-started) for Azure which you can directly deploy it to Azure via GitHub. Please refer to its [`web.config`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-python-get-started/blob/master/web.config) file & others to change your deployment to solve your current issue. Meanwhile, an offical tutorial [`Configuring Python with Azure App Service Web Apps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure) introduce how to configure Python on Azure App Service in details, which can help you.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I've tried to do that and what's quite weird is that even the template doesn't quite work and got error in them(different one though) and my webconfig is in fact a copy from the djangoa azure template.

Comment: @AufaHusen Could you post the file structure of your project on Azure like the sample project? I think the simple way to solve the issue is that create a WebApp from Django template and cover with your project files and change the related configure information.